# Generate a grid of quads which later can remove individual quad

Tags: opengl, grid, quad

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to generate a grid of quads. The idea is to later be able to remove a quad at will but didn't even come close to generate the grid.

I was thinking of using GL_TRIANGLE primitive but failed at setting up the buffer because of vertex order for a triangle.

I was having two for loops for width and height. So a grid of width x height (pseudo):

```
for y < height y++
  for x < width x++
    set vertex position (x,y,1)
```

That could work with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, but would that cause trouble later when trying to remove a quad (two triangles)?

I'm using opengl 3.3 and trying to use modern way of doing this. Also skipping indices.
I got a "basic" understanding of opengl, any help appreciated

[image: Illustrating grid and removing a quad]

Comment: " Also skipping indices." Why? It is both more efficient and will make your task much simpler.

Comment: well, i thought maybe it would make things easier later when i want to remove a quad